# Format xml in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have Notepad++ and XML Tools plugin installed.
When I copy an XML file and paste it to the window. It became one line. How can I auo format it and make it readable?

Thanks.

The demo image likes:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks)

Comment: It seems that version 6.5 doesn't have this plugin :(

Answer (score 3):

How about `Plugins - XML Tools - Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks)`? Default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. This should make your XML very readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find the plugin you want to use (eg.: XML Tools), just add it by clicking:

```
Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager
```

Find, select and install it. When you re-open Notepad++, it'll be listed under the Plugins menu.
After that, do what they've already said: `Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need [TextFX plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/).

Then go for:

> TextFX -> TextFX HTML Tidy -> Tidy: reindent XML

Comment: What NPP version do you have? I had a problem with libtidy.dll.

Comment: Newer versions of NPP require external installation of tidy. I've basically stopped using it and adopted XML Tools

Answer (score -1):

Better option is:

Plugins -> XML Tools -> Linarize XML

Comment: Does not this function format the XML back to a single line (i.e. contrary to what was asked for)?